# BigQueryIO.write() use SQL functions

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow streaming job. I am using BigqueryIO.write library to insert rows into BigQuery tables. There is a column in the BQ table, which is supposed to store the row creation timestamp. I need to use the SQL function "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()" to update the value of this column.

I can not use any of the java's libraries (like Instant.now()) to get the current timestamp. Because that will derive the value during the job execution. I am using a BigQuery load job, whose triggering frequency is 10 mins. So if I use any java libraries to derive the timestamp, then it won't return the expected output.

I could not find any method in BigqueryIO.write, which takes any SQL function as input. So what's the solution to this issue?

Comment: With row creation timestamp, do you mean the moment the element was generated? If so, you can use the `.timestamp()` method for the context in the DoFn. That should return the timestamp of the element itself.

Comment: @Iñigo, timestamp() method won't help. Because it will try to build the timestamp during the execution of the Dataflow job. But as I mentioned in the description, I need to use BigqueryIO File Load method to insert data into BQ table. The triggering frequency is 10mins, which means the actual BQ insertion will happen 20mins (or more based on the data volume it may divide it into multiple batches) after the Dataflow job execution.

Comment: `c.timestamp()` (with `c` being the context) would not try to build the timestamp during execution, but it would be the timestamp of the "creation" of the element. For example, if the elements are messages read from PubSub, `c.timestamp()` would the publish time of that message. Anyhow, not sure that would work on your case. Maybe use `withFormatFunction` and add the timestamp there?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want BigQuery to assign a timestamp to each row, based on when the row was inserted. The only way I can think of to accomplish this is to submit a QueryJob to BigQuery that contains an INSERT statement that includes `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` along with the values of the other columns. But this method is not particularly scalable with data volume, and it's not something that `BigQueryIO.write()` supports.

`BigQueryIO.write` supports batch loads, the streaming inserts API, and the Storage Write API, none of which to my knowledge provide a method to inject a BigQuery-side timestamp like you are suggesting.

Comment: Yes I have thought of using QueryJob. But I did not use it for the same reason which you explained. As the streaming job is expected to have heavy traffic, performance issue is a concern here.